# Restfull webservices + ejb

Tags: rest, jboss, ejb, resteasy

I'm working on simple web application using both ejb and resteasy following [this example](https://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/1.0.0.GA/userguide/html/RESTEasy_EJB_Integration.html). Unfortunately something does not work. 
My ear includes one jar with ejb beans and war containing only my `web.xml` file. 
Application deploys with no errors but I cannot access my services.
My beans:

```
@Local
@Path("/")
public interface IMyBean {

    @GET
    @Path("date")
    @Produces("text/plain")
    String getDate();

    @GET
    @Path("param/{param}")
    @Produces("text/plain")
    String getParam(@PathParam("param") String param);
}


@Stateless
public class MyBean implements IMyBean {

    @Override
    public String getDate() {
        return new Date();
    }

    @Override
    public String getParam(String param) {
        return param;
    }
}
```

And here is my `web.xml`:

```
<web-app>
    <display-name>Archetyp Created Web Application</display-name>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>resteasy.jndi.resources</param-name>
        <param-value>rest/AuthorizationBean/local</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Resteasy</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Resteasy</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Modules in my app got names: rest(jar with ejb beans), war (war archive) and ear(ear archive). I'm deploying on Jboss 7.1.1.

Comment: How are you trying to access you service? what happens?

Comment: I'm trying to access my `getDate()` method with following urls: localhost:8080/war/date, localhost:8080/ear/date, localhost:8080/date, but I'm still getting 404.

Answer (score 0):

Your URL pattern is correct. but path is not mentioned on the getDate() method. try below and use localhost:8080/war/date, localhost:8080/ear/date it will work

```
@GET
@Path("/date")
@Produces("text/plain")
String getDate();
```